# Is it possible to claim priority from two different applications?

Tags: pct, priority, description, merge

I have submitted two applications with different descriptions but which refer to the same concept. E.g. one application describes a substance in an oral pill form and the other application describes the same substance in an injectable form. I want to submit a PCT and merge the two applications claiming priority from both of them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. [Art. 8(1) PCT](https://www.wipo.int/pct/en/texts/articles/a8.html):

> The international application may contain a declaration, as
> prescribed in the Regulations, claiming the priority of one or more
> earlier applications filed in or for any country party to the Paris
> Convention for the Protection of Industrial Property.

And the fact that the two applications relate to the same concept has no bearing on priority or the content of another application.